# I'd like to invest in a fund available only to "qualified purchasers". How do I do it?

Tags: united-states, investing, mutual-funds, hedge-funds

Ideally, one would already have "[qualified purchaser](http://hedgefundlawblog.com/what-is-a-qualified-purchaser.html)" status in the US but if you don't already have it, what are your options?

The situation is difficult because I'd like to invest 1% of the minimum amount allowed by the fund so in addition to obtaining qualified purchaser status, I'd have to find other investors to provide the other 99%. However, I can probably find enough investors to complete the minimum amount.

I thought one way to solve the "qualified purchaser" problem would be persuading a fund managing company to set up a new trust with its own interested clients to invest in the fund I'm interested in. I'm currently trying to persuade one of them.

If that fails, what other options are there to invest in said hedge fund?

Can you think of a specific qualified purchaser who might be open to the idea of setting something up for small investments to enter the fund through them, probably for a fee?

Comment: How are taxes going to be handled? What about when one or more people want out? Or want profits distributed rather than reinvested?

Comment: Those are all interesting but entirely independent questions. I'll keep them in mind too.